# DataGrid в качестве RowDetailsTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

Есть `DataGrid`, при выборе строки которого выпадает `RowDetailsTemplate`, в `DataTemplate` указан еще один `DataGrid`. Суть в том что грид внутри `DataTemplate` привязан к `ObservableCollection` и должен отображать некоторую информацию в зависимости от выбранной строки основного `DataGrid`. Собственно разметка :

```
 <DataGrid x:Name="first" IsReadOnly="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="30" GridLinesVisibility="None" ItemsSource="{Binding ClientListCollection}" SelectedValue="{Binding KlientForDetails, Mode=OneWayToSource}">
            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectionChanged">
                    <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding SelectKlientForDetails}"/>
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding NameSimple}" Width="*" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding order}" MinWidth="100" Width="100"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <DataGrid x:Name="second" IsReadOnly = "True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" RowHeight="20" Height="100" ItemsSource="{Binding klientDetails,Mode=TwoWay}">
                            <DataGrid.Columns>
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding ="{Binding title}" Width="100" />
                                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding value}" Width="*"/>
                            </DataGrid.Columns>
                        </DataGrid>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
        </DataGrid>
```

Проблема в том, что при выборе строки `first` грида грид second разворачивается но совершенно пустым.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Однако если вывести `second`  из под `RowDetailsTemplate` 
 - заполняется как положено(т.е. дело не во вьюмо дели).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно конечно сделать 2 грида где один показывает просто список обьектов, а второй детальную информацию по нему  но хочется именно что бы при выборе строки, с `RowDetailsTemplate`. Как исправить эту разметку?

Comment: У меня работает, разметку особо не правил.

Comment: @sp7 У меня как на картинках. грид заполняется если вывести из `DataTemplate`

Comment: У вас `DataGrid` в `Grid` размещен?

Comment: @sp7 да. оба размещены

Comment: Размер строки `Grid`, в которой размещен `DataGrid` задан?

Comment: @sp7 `RowHeight` ? задан

Comment: В `<RowDefinition Height="здесь задано значение или нет"/>`

Comment: @sp7 а вот `RowDefinition`  не задавал.  каскад такой `DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate`->`DataTemplate`->`Grid`->`DataGrid`. В вопросе же написано.

Comment: Меня интересует основной `DataGrid` а не вложенный.

Comment: @sp7 В основном гриде не указывал `RowDefinition`.

Comment: У меня есть предположение, что это происходит из-за размеров контейнера, в котором размещен основной `DataGrid`. Давай я вам попозже приведу разметку окна, в  котором этих проблем нет.

Comment: @sp7 интересное предположение. попробую разобраться. в любом случае благодарен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня есть предположение, что это происходит из-за размеров контейнера, в котором размещен основной `DataGrid`. Поэтому как обещал в коментариях привожу разметку окна.

`XAML` код:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:WpfApplication4.ViewModel"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="500"
        Height="500"
        mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding ClientListCollection}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                    Binding="{Binding NameSimple}" />
                <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"
                                    MinWidth="100"
                                    Binding="{Binding Order}" />
            </DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModel:ParentViewModel}">

                    <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                              IsReadOnly="True"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding Details}">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="100"
                                                Binding="{Binding Title}" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Width="*"
                                                Binding="{Binding Value}" />
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>

                 </DataTemplate>
             </DataGrid.RowDetailsTemplate>
         </DataGrid>

         <Button Grid.Row="1"
                 Command="{Binding DoCommand}"
                 Content="Тыц" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

а так же `ViewModel`

```
public class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string NameSimple { get; set; } // INPC

    public string Order { get; set; } // INPC

    public ObservableCollection<DetailsViewModel> Details { get; set; }

    public ParentViewModel()
    {
        Details = new ObservableCollection<DetailsViewModel>();
    }
}

public class DetailsViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public string Title { get; set; } // INPC

    public int Value { get; set; } // INPC
}

public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<ParentViewModel> ClientListCollection { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        ClientListCollection = new ObservableCollection<ParentViewModel>();

        // Заполняем данными ClientListCollection...
    }
}
```

P.S. Некоторый вещи для вроде `EventTrigger` убраны для того что бы не загромождать  код.

Comment: к сожалению никакой разницы. можно было конечно грешить на неверную привязку, но родительский грид отображает корректно, если же вложенный начнет биндится к тем же обьектам то остается пустым(только хедеры столбцов).добавил `DataType` к `DataTemplate` и все равно не единой строки.

Comment: @Сергей у меня указанная разметка выглядит следующим образом http://s019.radikal.ru/i642/1707/e8/6289eb82ffd9.png Что бы понять что  конкретно у вас нужно видеть все окно целиком, привязка тут не причем. Данный пример лишь показывает, что разметка `DataGrid` у вас корректна.

Comment: она не может быть коректна. если поставить на оба грида привязку к одной коллекции то в основном гриде строки будут а во вложенном нет

Comment: @Сергей дак а зачем вам привязывать два `DataGrid` к одной коллекци? Так не правильно делать, дочерний `DataGrid` ищет данные в `DataContext` текущей строки и ничего там не находит. Структура `ViewModel`, которая привязывается к `DataGrid` должна быть примерно как в моем примере.

Comment: Не совсем понял. Дочерний датагрид ищет контекст в 'DataType'   'DataTemplate'  а не 'RowDefinition' же? Или я чего то не понимаю.

Comment: Нет, вы не правы. По умолчанию он осуществляет поиск как я написал. Если хотите сделать по-другому придется переписывать привязку.